# How to save pcap file to K12 text file using Python

Tags: python, pcap

I have a pcap file: a.pcap.
I can save this a.pcap to text file (.txt) with wireshark GUI (File -> Save as -> k12 text file).

How can I do the same thing with Python?

I have tried some methods, but the results are not as expected:

[image]

Images are manually saved as format.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do the same thing with Python?

Have the Python script run the command

```
editcap -F k12text a.pcap a.txt
```

Or, to do it *without* Python, just run that command yourself.